# Is that possible to add CodeContracts library to Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, code-contracts

I was just wondering, would I be able to add and use `CodeContracts` under `System.Diagnostics` in Visual Studion 2005?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the answer is no.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/10f23fc4-d9cb-44e2-98a8-36488e7c9f9c/code-contracts-and-vs2005

Given that you can only "prove" an application correct using the more expensive SKU, Code Contracts sort of acts like fancy assertions, which you can simulate withe the Should Library:

https://github.com/erichexter/Should

Or upgrade to a newer version of VS.